# Log4j is not printing logs

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

Following is my log4j.properties file log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, stdout

```
# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.tcs=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO

#log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ROLLOVERFILE, STDOUT,DEBUG

### Direct log4j properties to STDOUT ###  
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Configuration File
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=$\{java.io.tmpdir\}/log4j-test.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

in /src/main/resources/

Mine is Job-Scheduler based batch job. Logs are getting printed when I run my batch manually from putty. But when scheduler runs, logs are not getting printed. Only hibernate queries are getting printed.

The first line error I am getting is:

> ```
> log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.sos.JSHelper.Logging.JobSchedulerLog4JAppender].
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sos.JSHelper.Logging.JobSchedulerLog4JAppender
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:178)
>   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:319)
>   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:120)
>   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:629)
>   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
>   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
>   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
>   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
>   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
>   at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
>   at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:63)
>   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
>   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:301)
>   at com.tcs.telecom.tib.ibgateway.email.service.impl.EmailProcessor.<clinit>(EmailProcessor.java:13)
> log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.tcs.telecom.tib.ibgateway.email.service.impl.EmailProcessor).
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
> ```

Please suggest the way forward.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a dependency. Are you using a scheduling library like Quartz?

Comment: I have slf4j, log4j & slf4j-log4j libraries already added in my pom.xml. For Job-scheduler, I have separate sso-berlin job scheduler configuration which is not part of my project. Scheduler is running my code using a script file.

Comment: "For Job-scheduler, I have separate sso-berlin job scheduler configuration which is not part of my project" . So the scheduler is a separate project? (with separate pom.xml). Could you edit the question and show the pom files?